# Wrong pusher message response status

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I have implemented pusher in my Lumen v5.6 application project. Now I am facing that issue that If two users in in presence channel and each user has  its own event but when mobile device subscribed to pusher event and after sometime mobile device disconnect from internet but when another user/mobile device send message to that particular device/user then in one to one channel list user found which wrong because device has not internet of unsubscribed the channel and event. Now is there any another way to trace out that current message receiving user is available or connected to its event or not. Below is my working code

```
    public function triggerPusher($trigger, $receiver, $loginUser, $isCallback = false) {
        \Log::info("===== Trigger pusher ====");
        \Log::info($trigger);
        if (isset($trigger['data']['post'])) {
            $trigger['data']['post'] = $this->removeIndexes($trigger['data']['post'], ['bucket', 'is_collage']);
        }
        $this->initPusher();
        if ($sent_channel = $this->checkUserPresenceInChannel($trigger['channel'], $receiver)) {
            \Log::info("=== Pusher send channel ===");
            \Log::info($sent_channel);
            \Log::info("=== Pusher Trigger Event ===");
            \Log::info($trigger['event']);
            $this->sentStatus = (strpos($sent_channel, 'presence-message-chat') !== false) ? "V" : "D";
            // creating trigger data copy
//            $chatData = $this->prepareChatData($trigger['data']);
            return $this->pusher->trigger($sent_channel, $trigger['event'], array("data" => $trigger['data']), null, true);
        }
        \Log::info("=== Sent Via Push notification ===");
        return $this->triggerNotification($trigger['data'], $receiver, $loginUser, $isCallback);
    }
```

Kindly suggest any usefull solution or referece link.